# Converting an object to string with a specified culture

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any better way to convert a variable of Object type to a string with a specified culture (which is different from the Thread's default culture), rather than using such ugly ways as 1) trying to cast the object to all the types that support the `ToString(CultureInfo)` overload or 2) temporarily setting the thread's default culture?

Comment: wheres the object from that you do not know whats in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to cast it to the  `IConvertible` interface:

```
object o = ...;
string s = ((IConvertible)o).ToString(cultureInfo);
```

Comment: This is a pretty good way; unfortunately it doesn't work for certain types, for instance Exception.

Comment: `Exception` does not have such an overload.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use Convert.ToString(obj, cultureInfo). It makes all the casting under the hood.

```
public static string ToString(Object value, IFormatProvider provider) {
    IConvertible ic = value as IConvertible;
    if (ic != null) 
        return ic.ToString(provider);
    IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;
    if (formattable != null) 
        return formattable.ToString(null, provider);
    return value == null? String.Empty: value.ToString();
}
```

Source:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,6a1a2c3ac58e60dd

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format(culture, "{0}", obj);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28328072)

Comment: @jpgrassi can you please elaborate how does my reply not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: I can confirm that this actually works. Maybe the remark from jpgrassi was because code only answers are frowned upon.